# R: find overlapping regions using R

Tags: r, genetics

I have a data set that contains the initial and final position of segments on particular locations (scaffold), some of these segmens overlap with others if there are in the same scaffold.

```
> head(jobs)
JOB_N      Genome     Scaffold loc_i loc_f
     1 PRJNA179522 Contig10285  1251  1502
     1 PRJNA179522 Contig10285  1251  1602
     2 PRJNA179522 Contig10285  1255  1499
     2 PRJNA179522 Contig10285   828  1076
     2 PRJNA179522 Contig783     245  1487
     2 PRJNA179522 Contig783     822  1073
```

I want two things: the first one is to find all the overlapping regions in all the individual scaffolds. 
The second is to obtain a new table that contain only the first and the final position of each "new" segment. The ouput would be:

```
JOB_N      Genome     Scaffold loc_i loc_f
     1 PRJNA179522 Contig10285  1251  1602
     2 PRJNA179522 Contig10285   828  1076
     2 PRJNA179522 Contig783     245  1487
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See `foverlaps` in `data.table` or `findOverlaps` in `IRanges`

Answer (score 2):

You've specified 'individual scaffold', but your example output has a duplicated scaffold. Do you want to include `JOB_N` and `Genome` in those groups as well?

If so, one `data.table` method is to find the `min` and `max` of `loc_i` and `loc_f` respectively, for each required *group*

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(jobs)

dt[, .(min_loc_i = min(loc_i), max_loc_f = max(loc_f)), by=.(JOB_N, Genome, Scaffold)]

#   JOB_N      Genome    Scaffold min_loc_i max_loc_f
#1:     1 PRJNA179522 Contig10285      1251      1602
#2:     2 PRJNA179521 Contig10285      1251      1499
#3:     2 PRJNA179522 Contig10285       828      1076
#4:     2 PRJNA179522   Contig783       245      1487
```

If you do only want individual scaffolds you only need to group by `scaffold`

```
dt[, .(min_loc_i = min(loc_i), max_loc_f = max(loc_f)), by=.(Scaffold)]
#      Scaffold min_loc_i max_loc_f
#1: Contig10285       828      1602
#2:   Contig783       245      1487
```

Comment: Maybe the description was wrong. I spect that I will have a lot of segments  (exons) in each scaffold. is for that reason that I need to find all the overlapping regions. If you pay attention, in my example, #1 and #2 are overlapping segments  but #3 not. So, there are 2 independent segments (those that don't overlapp) in the scaffold "Contig10285". It's clear now? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MJRC ok I think I understand you now. I'll make an edit to my answer